# How to create a new culture version for multiple pages in Kentico at one go?

Tags: multilingual, kentico, kentico-mvc, kentico-12

I am configuring a new language version on the existing Kentico 12 website. I can easily create a new culture version of a page by copying content from the already existing language, but a problem is that this feature is available at a page level only what in my case, having hundreds of pages, will results to many hours of manual efforts. Ideally, I would like to select multiple pages and create the new culture version for all of them at once.

Could you please advise me on how I can optimise this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would be able to do it in 2 steps with the help of Translations application.

First, multiple (or all) pages can be submitted for translation via Listing view

[image: listing]

Next, select here source and destination languages to copy pages and click "Translate":

[image: translate]

Then you will see pages with "Ready for translation" status

[image: ready for translation pages]

Next, go to the "Translations" application and edit the submission:

[image: translation submission]

And finally, click "Export all to ZIP", this will download a ZIP file. Then click "Import all from ZIP" and use the just downloaded ZIP file. Then click "Process translations" and that's it!

[image: process translations]